# Visual Studio Code peek/go to definition not working when imports are specified with project name

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I am working with javascript. Usual cases the imports would look like:

`import reducerUtils from '../../utils/reducerUtils'`

And the `peek definition` or `go to definition` on `reducerUtils` works as expected.

Things goes different when I change the import to:

```
import reducerUtils from 'projectname/src/utils/reducerUtils'
```

The path is definitely valid and the app works too but in the editor the `peek definition` or `go to definition` does not work anymore

I understand this could be a standard issue looking from the editors perspective but I was just looking for any solution here to make it work. It might involve into some configuration changes somewhere but my search had no luck. Help Would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding a `jsconfig.json` file at the root(or wherever appropriate depending on the project). Specify the `paths` under `compilerOptions`. eg,

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "projectname/*": ["./*"], //it's root in my case
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Bit more closer look:
https://medium.com/@justintulk/solve-module-import-aliasing-for-webpack-jest-and-vscode-74007ce4adc9

Official Doc: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig